# Why am I getting invalid "XML for View Architecture" after adding new model in OpenERP 7?

Tags: python, xml, openerp-7

This is My python File

```python
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class scantech_product_template(osv.osv):

    _inherit='product.product' 

    _column={
       'main_cat':fields.integer("Main Category",size=11)
    }  

scantech_product_template()
```

This is XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record  model= "ir.ui.view" id= "scantech_product_normal_form_view">
            <field name="name">product.normal.form</field>
            <field name= "model">product.product</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name= "arch" type="xml">
                <field name="type" position="after">
                <field name="main_cat"/>
            </field>    
            </field>
        </record>   
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I got Invalid XML view. Tell me the correct code for it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record  model= "ir.ui.view" id= "scantech_product_normal_form_view">
            <field name="name">product.normal.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.product</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="type" position="after">
                    <field name="main_cat" />
                </field>
            </field>    
        </record>   
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Thanx.. This is working for me... but after that Invalid XML view error is gone but it showing unable to load "database_name"

Comment: Yes this is the error that its not loading my database.. wait I will provide my error log

Comment: 1. XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: record line 4 and field, line 13, column 21

Comment: ERROR laser openerp: Failed to initialize database `laser`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/cli/server.py", line 97, in preload_registry
    db, registry = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool(dbname,update_module=update_module)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 203, in get
    update_module)

Comment: Are you sure you are update in the right way? What command do you use to run Odoo? Notice that you wrote `name= "model"` with one space in the middle and it should be like this `name="model"`, without the space. Check if it works without spaces

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I've paste your sample code still it give me above error.. but after checking there is one extra </field> when I removed it. then errors are gone automatically. but thank you so much for your help sir.

Comment: Ah you are right, one extra `</field>`. Im going to change my answer, please mark is as correct in order to close the question